# JDBC ResultSet not iterating all rows

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, resultset

I need a second pair of eyes on some code.  I feel like there's something simple I'm missing.  I have a table in my MariaDB called jeff_tables, which contains 4 entries.  I've created a utility thread that runs the following code inside the run method:

```
try {
        getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM jeff_tables";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        //rs.last(); //returns 4 rows
        //System.out.println("result set size: " + rs.getRow() );
        while(rs.next()) {
            Integer tenant = rs.getInt("TENANT_ID");
            String table = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.println("Inserting k-v pair: " + tenant + " " + table);
            tableNames.put(tenant, table);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I uncomment the rs.last() and rs.getRow() lines, it returns 4, which is the correct number of entries it should return.  However, what's actually happening is it enters my while loop, prints the correct values for the first row, then throws a null pointer on the put statement.  I've also tried running this code outside of a thread, but it's doing the same thing.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently `tableNames` variable is not initialized and is `null`

Comment: Yea, I realized that right after I posted this question.  I knew it was something simple that I kept overlooking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I posted this, I saw the problem.  This was just a simple instance of forgetting to instantiate the HashMap before trying to insert values into it.  It's funny how sometimes it takes posting a question to open your eyes.